First-price sealed bid auction with a non-uniform valuation distribution
Let's imagine a two-player Bayesian auction game with sealed bids and independent and private valuations of the auctioned good. The question is to calculate the optimal bidding strategy $b_{i}(v_{i})$ for both players. I know how to solve the simplest case, where $v_{i}$ is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.
(This is how we did it in class. You define $k_{i}$ as $\frac{b_{i}}{v_{i}}$ and then denote profit as $$\pi_{A}=(v_{A}-b_{A})\cdot P(b_{A}>b_{B})\\\pi_{A}=(v_{A}-b_{A})\cdot P(\frac{b_{A}}{k_{B}}>v_{B})$$
However, since we assumed uniform continuous distribution of $v_{B}$, the probability $P(\frac{b_{A}}{k_{B}}>v_{B})=\frac{b_{A}}{k_{B}}$. After that, optimization goes smoothly.)
I tried solving two different examples:
a) $v_{i}$ is distributed between 0 and 1 with the pdf $P(v)=-6x^2+6x$.
b) $v_{i}$ is distributed normally with $\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sigma=\frac{1}{6}$.
In both cases, I failed miserably at calculating the probability $P(\frac{b_{A}}{k_{B}}>v_{B})$. Could you help me with this?
Thanks!

"After  that the optimization goes smoothly." Please edit your post to show the details. What result did you get for an optimal bidding function $b(v)$ and the associated expected profit $\pi$?
